# Log4j Logging with JBOSS5

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss5.x

I am using log4j as logging framework in my application and JBOSS 5 as Application server. I have created a log4j.properties file in the src folder of the application. That's how my **log4j.properties** looks like:

```
#Default log level to ERROR. Other levels are INFO and DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ROOT
log4j.appender.ROOT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
##Uncomment the next line and comment the 2nd next line when ready to deploy
log4j.appender.ROOT.File=/www/public/logs/myapp.log
##log4j.appender.ROOT.File=C:/myapp.log
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxFileSize=100KB
#Keep 5 old files around.
log4j.appender.ROOT.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#Format almost same as WebSphere's common log format.
log4j.appender.ROOT.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %t %c %-5p - %m%n

#Optionally override log level of individual packages or classes
log4j.logger.com.webage.ejbs=INFO
```

But I can see that the **myapp.log** is never been created so I am not able to see any logs. Also I can server.log file in the sever logs folder but it has so much verbose that it's hard to track what's going on there. So I have two questions:
1. Why myapp.log is not being created. 
2. Do u think the log4j.property file shown above is sufficient or not need to configure more stuff here.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 7):

Most likely your log4j.properties is not getting picked up.

To configure log4j in Jboss 5 you would edit the file at

```
server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml
```

If you still want to use log4j.propeties, In the webapp, it should be placed in in your `deploy/myapp.war/WEB-INF/classes`

Follow the detailed instuctions at section **"10.3.7. Using your own log4j.properties file - class loader scoping"** in [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html)

Comment: If I'm using JBoss 5.1, is this the only way to to get application-specific log4j rules setup using a log4j.properties file?  Is there a way to do this without changing `jboss-log4j.xml`?